# The shortest confidence interval (in the sense of expectation) for two sample t test when variances are unknown and unequal

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, heteroscedasticity, exact-test

I have had a question since graduate school. For a given significance level alpha, the test with smallest confidence interval length expectation should be optimal, because it usually also means a higher power, with fixed Type I error. But textbooks hardly mentioned that.

I also notice that $t$-statistics with degree of freedom $n$ can be written as the following expression (ignore the constant term), where $\chi_j^2 = X_j^2$ are squares of i.i.d. normal variables $X_j$:
$$t_n^2 = \frac{\chi_0^2}{\sum_i^n \chi_i^2}$$

**But what if we design a new statistics $t^p$?**

$$t_n^p = \frac{\chi_0^p}{\sum_i^n \chi_i^p}, \chi_i^p = |X_i|^p, (t_n^p \not = (t_n^2)^{p/2})$$

Will it lead to a shorter confidence interval expectation? It is also a fixed distribution, and can be used to derive a confidence interval. **Why do we use $t^2$? Is that just a coincidence (it is the easiest) or is it optimal?**

I drafted a short paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.16473) to demonstrate that this is practical, also shows its confidence interval length expectation's first derivative is zero at p=2. But the convexity is still unknown. (According to simulation, I guess p=2 is the best.)

**Q1, Do you have any ideas about how to address this question? Have you ever come across similar topic/literature about minimizing CI?** I think it might be the first one, because it creates a new independent partition of information, which makes such test possible.

By the way, in that paper I also propose a two sample mean test, Te test, which is alway exact (type one error always equal to alpha), even when variances of two normal distributions are not equal, and sample sizes are different.  https://github.com/hobbitish1028/Te_test Here is the package for that. It also shows a simulation when the Welch test is significantly worse than mine ($\mu_1=\mu_2=0$,$\sigma_1=1,\sigma_2=2,n_1=5,n_2=50$).

**Q2, Another question is: Why people stick to use Welch's t-test when there can be exact test?**
Possible reasons includes:

- Unbalanced case like $n_1=5,n_2=50$ are rare in real life.
- Small sample size case usually has low power, people prefer higher power, even with the price of inaccurate type-one error.
- People just get used to that.

Really look forward to all kinds of discussion!